# How do I start Eclipse-Hono client in MQTT?

Tags: mqtt, eclipse-hono

I'm having trouble in starting MQTT Client in Eclipse Hono.
I'm using The following command to start the client

```
java -jar hono-example-0.6-exec.jar --hono.client.host=hono.eclipse.org --hono.client.port=15672 --hono.client.username=consumer@HONO --hono.client.password=verysecret --spring.profiles.active=receiver --tenant.id=bob
```

which starts the client accepting telemetry data produced by the device, but didn't catch the data published through MQTT.

What may be wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are using does not start an MQTT client but starts the receiver for consuming (AMQP 1.0) messages from devices belonging to tenant *bob*. In order to see something happening, you need to have a device that belongs to tenant *bob* publish some data. If you want to use MQTT for that purpose you may want to use the *mosquitto_pub* command line client as described in the Getting Started guide. However, make sure that you use the correct username and password. From what I can see in the device registry on hono.eclipse.org you have registered a device with id 1112 and auth-id *sensor1*. So the command to publish should look something like:

```
mosquitto_pub -h hono.eclipse.org -u sensor1@bob -Pthepasswordyouregistered -t telemetry -m "hello"
```

Again, make sure to replace *thepasswordyouregistered* with the real password that you have registered for device 1112.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir, actually I was confused in the client service that I have to start a new client in order to receive messages passed through MQTT adapter.

Comment: Have you been able to publish and receive messages following the steps outlined in my answer? If so, it would be nice if you could accept the answer.